# How to pass unique_ptr<T> in place of a raw *output* pointer parameter?

Tags: c++, c++11, unique-ptr

I have a *pre-existing* function in an *external* library, which looks like this;

```
bool CreateTheThing(MyThing *& pOut);
```

In short; I give it a raw pointer (by reference), and the function allocates memory and assigns my pointer to the newly-allocated object.  When the function returns, it is *my* responsibility to free the memory, when I'm done.

Obviously, I'd like to store this result into a `unique_ptr<MyThing>`, and avoid the manual `delete`.

I *could* create a temporary raw pointer to use with the API call, and pass it into the constructor for the `unique_ptr`;

```
MyThing* tempPtr;
CreateTheThing(tempPtr);
unique_ptr<MyThing> realPtr = unique_ptr<MyThing>(tempPtr);
```

Is there a more direct method than this?  One which doesn't require a temporary raw pointer?  Ideally, there would be a method of `unique_ptr` which exposes its internal pointer in a way that could work directly with the `CreateTheThing` method?

`unique_ptr<T>::get()` does not allow this, to my knowledge.  The pointer it returns is not a reference to the internally-used pointer.

Comment: Does the library require you to use `free()` to deallocate?

Comment: Any reason it doesn't just return a pointer?

Comment: Ah, too bad. The external library forces you to write silly code.

Comment: You can shorten the realPtr line to `unique_ptr<MyThing> realPtr(tempPtr);`

Comment: Yes, or!:  `auto realPtr = unique_ptr<MyThing>(tempPtr)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can save one line of code (potentially many times) by writing many lines of code once:

```
class Wrapper
{
  std::unique_ptr<MyThing> &u;
  MyThing *p;

public:
  Wrapper(std::unique_ptr<MyThing> &u) : u(u), p() {}

  operator MyThing* & ()
  { return p; }

  ~Wrapper()
  { u.reset(p); }
};
```

Usage:

```
std::unique_ptr<MyThing> u;
CreateTheThing(Wrapper(u));
```

Comment: Neat!  `template<typename T> class out_ptr_adapter;`

Comment: @BTownTKD Plus a `template <class T> make_out_ptr_adapter()` for type deduction, of course.

Comment: **p** should be initialized with **nullptr** for exception safety.

Comment: @CAF `p` is value-initialised (note `p()` in the ctor mem-initialiser list), which means it will be a null pointer.

Answer (score 11):

> Is there a more direct method than this? One which doesn't require a temporary raw pointer?

No, there isn't.

> Ideally, there would be a method of unique_ptr which exposes its internal pointer in a way that could work directly with the CreateTheThing method?  `unique_ptr::get()` does not allow this, to my knowledge.

Your knowledge is correct. That would defeat the whole purpose of the `std::unique_ptr`, therefore `unique_ptr::get()` is a `const` function and the pointer is returned by value.

However similar as your constructor example, you can always use `std::unique_ptr::reset()` to pass an externally allocated pointer.

Also note: If the 3rd party API requires you to release the memory using `free()` you may need to provide a special deleter function for the `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: Clear, concise and definitive answer.  Thank you very much!

Comment: nitpick: `unique_ptr::get()` returning the pointer *by-value* is why you can't change what is stored through it.

Comment: @Caleth Better?

Answer (score 4):

If you use the function often you could put the conversion in a function.

Best would be to change the API, but this can also work.

```
inline std::unique_ptr<MyThing> CreateTheThing()
{
  MyThing* p;
  if (CreateTheThing(p))
  {
    return std::unique_ptr<MyThing>(p);
  }
  return std::unique_ptr<MyThing>();
}
```

You could also make this overload to make refactoring even easier:

```
inline bool CreateTheThing(std::unique_ptr<MyThing>& ptr)
{
    try 
    {
        MyThing* p;
        if (CreateTheThing(p))
            ptr = std::unique_ptr<MyThing>(p);
        else
            return false;
    }
    catch (std::bad_alloc&)
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: `CreateTheThing()` is the function called from the external library. I doubt that the OP can simply change it.

Comment: That's correct.  I've edited the question for clarity.  I'd like to avoid changing the legacy API in the external library.

Comment: IMO This is the best answer because you can use it to force the rest of the application to use the new method by hiding the old `API` behind the new, wrapper, function API. Then you know that no one will be wandering off with stray owning raw pointers.

Comment: This solution does not hide the original api.  It provides an override.  There is no way to hide a global function.

Comment: It's not virtual, so it doesn't "override" anything. But yes, it is an **overload** that does not hide or otherwise interfere with the original `CreateTheThing()`. I'm not sure what @Galik meant; maybe they can clarify.

Comment: @MichaëlRoy It doesn't have to hide the original API, but you can use it to if you want to which would be my preferred way.